# multidimensional Array out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am doing something wrong and cannot figure out. I have a multidimentional matrix `total` this stores. I am messing up the sequencing somewhere just cannot understand how or why. The error is `IndexError: index 253 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 253`

```
class pricing_floatinglookback:
def __init__(self, spot, rate, sigma, time, sims, steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps+1
    self.dt = self.time / self.steps

def call_floatingstrike(self):

    SimPriceMin = np.array([])
    SimPriceAtMaturity = np.array([])
    call2 = np.array([])
    pathwiseS= np.zeros((self.steps,),float)
    total = np.zeros((self.sims,self.steps),float)       
    for j in range(self.sims):
        pathwiseS[0] =self.spot## This will be one dimensional array from 0 to 253
        total[j,0] = self.spot ## This will be multidimensional array with columns 0 to 800 and rows 0 to 253
        for i in range(self.steps):
            phi = np.random.normal()
            pathwiseS[i+1] = pathwiseS[i]*(1+self.rate*self.dt+self.sigma*phi*np.sqrt(self.dt))## -->This is where i am going wrong.
            total[j,i+1]= pathwiseS[i+1] ## -->This is where i am going wrong.

        SimPriceAtMaturity = np.append(SimPriceAtMaturity, pathwiseS[self.steps - 1])
        call2 = np.append(call2,max((pathwiseS[self.steps - 1])-self.spot,0))
        SimPriceMin = np.append(SimPriceMin, min(pathwiseS))

    callbsm = np.average(call2)
    call = max(np.average(SimPriceAtMaturity) - np.average(SimPriceMin), 0)
    return call, total.reshape(self.sims, self.steps), np.average(SimPriceMin), callbsm*np.exp(-self.rate*self.time)

pricelookback = pricing_floatinglookback(100, 0.05, 0.2, 1, 800, 252)
clookback, callmatrix, calmin, callbsm = pricelookback.call_floatingstrike()
print (callbsm)
plt.plot(callmatrix.T)
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `total[j,i+1]= pathwiseS[i+1]` by perhaps `total[j,i]= pathwiseS[i+1]`? By doing `i+1` you are trying to access 253 index which does not exist. The reason is that the indexing in python starts from 0. So an array of length 253 will have its last index as 252

Comment: well - python is 0-based indexing, a  `axis 0 with size 253` values has indexes from 0...252 - 253 is out of bounds...

Comment: @Sheldore its the same error when I do `total[j,i]= pathwiseS[i+1]` Edited where the issues is its in the line before

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know that but if you look on top I am assigning a value of 253 to `self.steps` not 252.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. I don't know why or how but it's fixed

```
class pricing_floatinglookback:
def __init__(self, spot, rate, sigma, time, sims, steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps+1
    self.dt = self.time / self.steps

def call_floatingstrike(self):

    SimPriceMin = np.array([])
    SimPriceAtMaturity = np.array([])
    call2 = np.array([])
    pathwiseS= np.zeros((self.steps,),float)
    total = np.zeros((self.sims,self.steps),float)       
    for j in range(self.sims):
        pathwiseS[0] =self.spot
        total[j,0] = self.spot
        for i in range(self.steps-1):##--->This was the main reason, dont know why but it was!
            phi = np.random.normal()
            pathwiseS[i+1] = pathwiseS[i]*(1+self.rate*self.dt+self.sigma*phi*np.sqrt(self.dt))
            total[j,i]= pathwiseS[i+1]##--->This as suggested in the comments

        SimPriceAtMaturity = np.append(SimPriceAtMaturity, pathwiseS[self.steps - 1])
        call2 = np.append(call2,max((pathwiseS[self.steps - 1])-self.spot,0))
        SimPriceMin = np.append(SimPriceMin, min(pathwiseS))

    callbsm = np.average(call2)
    call = max(np.average(SimPriceAtMaturity) - np.average(SimPriceMin), 0)
    return call, total.reshape(self.sims, self.steps), np.average(SimPriceMin), callbsm*np.exp(-self.rate*self.time)
```